# Flex Template Python dependency management without outbound network connectivity

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

we are running Dataflow Python Flex Templates in a VPC without outbound network connectivity and without artifact repository. Hence, for Dataflow python *jobs*, we provide dependencies as described here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#local-or-nonpypi.

What is the best practice to provide dependencies to Python *Flex Templates*, where the build process that builds the docker image has access to PyPI, but the Dataflow workers don't have access?

Comment: Facing the same problem - did you find a solution?